# Symfony2 and Apache is fulling memory RAM when press F5 many times

Tags: mysql, apache, symfony, ubuntu, web

I have a website with 30,000 visits / month and all works fine but when a visitor or I press F5 many times for reload a page, symfony and apache full the memory and MySQL is stopped causing that the website crash and then I need start mysql service one more time (sudo service mysql start) this problem is happening all the weeks 1 or 2 times per day and I don't know what to do.

I am using APC cache, Symfony 2.6, MySQL and Ubuntu 14
The mysql and apache's logs says nothing.

Answer (score 1):

APC is not enough, you should use memcache or redis coupled for your templates coupled with ESI as Michael suggest.

Here are some links to optimize your application with those two caching technology :

http://labs.octivi.com/handling-1-billion-requests-a-week-with-symfony2/

Your system must be much more optimized after refactoring.

Start by checking your homepage which parts are always the same to cache to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use some reverse proxy like Varnish. If you have some valuable data that are need to be updated at every request you should use ESI. Varnish provide ESI functionality.